# I need to increase and decrease button.width using ScrollBar changing ( C# Win Form)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am trying to change button.width using scrollbar (increase and decrease).
for example: when hScrollBar.value =10 then button1.Width increase by 10 and so on.
I start with this code :
private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
 { button1.width = hScrollBar1.value;}

but the issue is button1.width will equal to zero( when decrease hScrollBar1 to minimum!).
Hope some one have good condition to avoid this issue.

thanks

Comment: button1.Width = Math.Max(50, hScrollBar1.Value);

Comment: that makes button1.width not increase until hScrollBar.value =50.
but, I need for example: when hScrollBar.value =10 then button1.Width increase by 10 and so on.
thanks

Comment: button1.Width = 50 + hScrollBar1.Value;  This is too obvious to be useful, highly doubtful that this is sensible UI design.

Comment: I agree , the question is too obvious and too specific to be useful. also, there is a specific tool to format the code section of your question. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Hans, Thanks Mina.
it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
button1.Width = constant_size + hScrollBar1.Value
```

constant_size can be any number you like the default size of the button to be, assuming that hScrollBar1 returns non-negative value